# Consistent way of getting labels from plot, bar and other drawings with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

With line plots, I can get all labels like this and build a legend:

```
p1 = ax1.plot(x, 'P1', data=df)
p2 = ax1.plot(x, 'P2', data=df)
p3 = ax1.plot(x, 'P3', data=df)
p4 = ax1.plot(x, 'P4', data=df)

p = p1+p2+p3+p4
labs = [l.get_label() for l in p]
ax1.legend(p, labs, loc=0, frameon=False)
```

When I have bar plots, this does not work anymore. E.g.:

```
b1 = ax1.bar(x-2*w, 'B1', data=df, width=w, label="TP")
b2 = ax1.bar(x-w, 'B2', data=df, width=w, label="FN")
b3 = ax1.bar(x, 'B3', data=df, width=w, label="FP")
b4 = ax2.bar(x+w, 'B4', data=df, width=w, label="AP")
b5 = ax2.bar(x+2*w, 'B5', data=df, width=w, label="AR")
```

`b1.get_label()` returns a string similar to a `__str__` method:

```
'0    87
Name: TP, dtype: object'
```

Why does `.get_label()` not behave identically?

Comment: What version of Matplotlib are you using? I don't see this issue with version 3.6.0. In that version the `get_label()` method returns the label text as expecting for both line plots and bar plots.

Comment: @MattPitkin I am using 3.5.2

Comment: Hmmm, I'd expect that version to have the same behaviour as 3.6.0. Both the `Line2D` object that `plot` returns and the `Container` object that `bar` returns, should use the [`get_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_label.html) attribute of an `Artist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax1.plot(...)` returns a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) of Line2D elements.  Usually this is a tuple of just one element, but it can be longer when more lines are plotted in the same call (`lines = ax1.plot(x1,y1,'r',x2,y2,'b')` would return 2 Line2D elements).

When you do `p1+p2+p3+p4`, you append these tuples, creating a tuple of 4 elements.  `ax.bar`, on the other hand, returns a single Bar container.  These can't be concatenated via `+`. You need to create a tuple `(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5)` or a list `[b1,b2,b3,b4,b5]`.

You'll often see a mysterious comma used in `p1, = ax1.plot(...)`. That way, the first element of the tuple is assigned to `p1`.

Also note that you don't need to extract the labels.  If you call `ax1.legend(handles=p)`, matplotlib will extract and use these labels automatically.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(20)
df = pd.DataFrame({f'P{i}': np.random.randn(20).cumsum() for i in range(1, 5)})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
p1 = ax1.plot(x, 'P1', data=df)
p2 = ax1.plot(x, 'P2', data=df)
p3 = ax1.plot(x, 'P3', data=df)
p4 = ax1.plot(x, 'P4', data=df)

p = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
ax1.legend(handles=p, loc='best', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: calling handles]

The same can be written as follows, making it easier to combine handles from different functions:

```py
p1, = ax1.plot(x, 'P1', data=df)
p2, = ax1.plot(x, 'P2', data=df)
p3, = ax1.plot(x, 'P3', data=df)
p4, = ax1.plot(x, 'P4', data=df)

p = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
ax1.legend(handles=p, frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

That makes it similar to how you would work with bars:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({f'B{i}': np.random.rand(5).cumsum() for i in range(1, 6)})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
w = 0.19
b1 = ax1.bar(x - 2 * w, 'B1', data=df, width=w, label="TP")
b2 = ax1.bar(x - w, 'B2', data=df, width=w, label="FN")
b3 = ax1.bar(x, 'B3', data=df, width=w, label="FP")
b4 = ax1.bar(x + w, 'B4', data=df, width=w, label="AP")
b5 = ax1.bar(x + 2 * w, 'B5', data=df, width=w, label="AR")

ax1.legend(handles=[b1, b2, b3, b4, b5], frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with legend from handles]

Of course, in these cases, the legend can also be created automatically. However, explicit working with these handles can be interesting if you need finetuning the legend, or you want to combine two handles into one.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with `handles`, did not know that.

Comment: Matplotlib's [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) has many examples, including one where a red dot and a white cross are combined.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work out. I supplied the labels as list to the call of `ax.legend()`. Whenever I go by handles, the labels of the bar plots in the legend contain the y values of bars, and a type information. I tried `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` as well, but then the labels too contain the additional (garbage) information. Then I upgraded from 3.5.2 to 3.6.2, no change. Now I am fighting the legend position, it is shown outside the figures bbox to the right, but its cutted as there is not enough space for it. But thats a topic for another SO question.

Comment: `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` gets the assigned labels (such as `"TP"` in  `ax1.bar(... label="TP")` and the corresponding handles.  To see the full legend, you can call `plt.tight_layout()` at the end, just before `plt.show()`.

Comment: with `get_legend_handles_labels()` 2 lists are returned, the handles and the labels. The labels from the first axis contain only one string which was set with labels="" on one bar, the remaining entries on the labels list of ax1 are numbers of three other columns of the dataframe. The labels list from ax2 (created with ax1.twinx()) contain only the numbers of the two columns of the df which were put on ax2. There no label="" value appears in the labels list. However, I can fix this by assigning the labels directly to the ax.legend() call.

Comment: And before plotting the figure, `plt.tight_layout()` is called and then the figure saved with `plt.savefig(file_name, bbox_extra_artists=[lgd], bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)`, where `lgd` is the handle returned by `lgd = ax1.legend(labels=['Annotations', 'TP', 'FN', 'FP', 'AP', 'AR'], mode="expand", frameon=False, loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1), borderaxespad=0.)`

Comment: Interesting is the following: When the data in the df is generated using the statement from your example (with `np.random.rand(5).cumsum()`), as opposed to use the df with the data from my experiments, the labels are correct. The code for generating the figure is identical for both dataframes. However, the legend is cutted on both examples.

Comment: If you plot from a dataframe as in `ax1.plot(x, 'P1', data=df)`, matplotlib automatically puts the column name as label. So, as if you'd call `ax1.plot(x, 'P1', data=df, label='P1')`.  If you don't want a label, matplotlib has a convention that labels starting with an underscore (`_`) are ignored.